# Windows 2008 vbs script execution error

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, windows-server-2008

I am running a very simple vbs file on windows server 2008 32 bit (IIS7 on it) which has following content

`set databrowser = Server.CreateObject("myDLL.DataBrowser")`

it gives me following error,

> Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.7 Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\test.vbs(1, 1) Microsoft VBScript
>   runtime error : Object required: 'Server'

I am running as `cscript.exe test.vbs`

what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Wscript.Createobject` instead of Server.CreateObject.

See: [What's the Difference between WScript.CreateObject, Server.CreateObject and CreateObject?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/06/01/145686.aspx)

Comment: +1 But I'd just use `CreateObject` so the code is transportable between ASP and CScript hosting.

Comment: Thanks man.. it worked in .vbs file :) but when i put same line in .asp file then it gave me "object required : ''" error

Comment: @swd in ASP it should be `Server.CreateObject`. But as @AnyhonyWJones said, maybe you can just simply write `CreateObject` (with no prefix object) and it will work in both environments.